# How can I implement service layer in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I see in this article [1](https://breadcrumbscollector.tech/how-to-implement-a-service-layer-in-django-rest-framework/) and also in this video [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG3ZdxBb1oo) that is very helpful to build your REST application in Django using a service layer because put your business logic in Model Layer or in View Layer isn't the best choice. Can you share with me some simple models of services in Django ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best DRF based enterprise Applications are developed with following structure over Django and DRF :-

- Proxy Models (i.e purpose - your default model remains clean, all your object based
  business logic goes here.)
- Custom Managers (i.e purpose - DAO (Data Access Logic) goes here, also we can achieve
  re-usability of code)
- Service Layer (i.e purpose - core business logic goes here, therefore your views class
  has more readability)

Example For Service Layer :

```
class RecoInfoService():

    def get_initiated_reco_detail(self, request, id):
        obj = RecoInfoProxy.objects.get_initiated_reco_by_id(id=id)
        serial_data = GetRecoInfoSerializer(obj)
        return Response(serial_data.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


    def initiate_reco(self, request):
        line_items_service = LineItemsService()
        print(request.data, type(request.data),"in INITIA")
        serial_data = RecoInfoSerializer(data=request.data, many=True, context={'request':request})
        if serial_data.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            with transaction.atomic(), reversion.create_revision():
                createdObj = reversion_post(request, serial_data)
                self.trigger_reco_initiation_notification(createdObj)
                line_items_service.prefetch_reco_initiation_lineitems(createdObj)
            return createdObj
```

Now from your `views.py`, call this service methods as:

```
class RecoInfoView(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        operation = kwargs.get('operation')
        initiate_reco_service = RecoInfoService()
        if operation == 'request':
            reco_info_obj = initiate_reco_service.initiate_reco(request)
            return Response('msg  : Initiate Reco Successfull')
```

Comment: Looking at the example `RecoInfoService` depends on `LineItemsService` should services be hierarchal to prevent circular dependencies? or should the `LineItemsService` be `LineItemUtil` or something like that?

Comment: I don't think this is completly correct. What is the point of having serialization/deserialization in the service?. The service layer should be agnostic of the presentation layer, it should receive and return objects. Returning Respose would make it only work with the View making it impossible to work with other services.

Comment: This is not service layer, you are creating new objects, a Service is something which is instantiated once and injected in all other services.